# Spring Data MongoDB + Spring Boot starting twice?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to make Spring Data MongoDB (reactive) work with Spring Boot 2.1.5 (and WebFlux).

From the startup logs I suspect that something is wrong, it seems like it's initialized twice (note the two repository scans, and they even return different results):

```
2019.05.19 11:59:53 | INFO | org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019.05.19 11:59:55 | INFO | org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1235ms. Found 8 repository interfaces.
2019.05.19 11:59:55 | INFO | org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019.05.19 11:59:55 | INFO | org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 64ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019.05.19 11:59:59 | INFO | org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2019.05.19 11:59:59 | INFO | org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2019.05.19 11:59:59 | INFO | org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Adding discovered server localhost:27017 to client view of cluster
2019.05.19 12:00:00 | INFO | org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:13}] to localhost:27017
2019.05.19 12:00:00 | INFO | org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 9]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=16058831}
2019.05.19 12:00:00 | INFO | org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Discovered cluster type of STANDALONE
2019.05.19 12:00:00 | INFO | org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:14}] to localhost:27017
2019.05.19 12:00:00 | INFO | org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 9]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=43838433}
```

There is nothing special in my build file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")

    ...

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}
```

There is absolutely no Java configuration regarding Mongo, only `application.properties` settings:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.database=mydb
spring.data.mongodb.username=myuser
spring.data.mongodb.password=mypass
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is something making you think there's a problem *after* startup?

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, just a starter project, not sure if this is OK or not.

Comment: It looks like it's trying to startup a MongoDB cluster? Note the 2 log lines with `mode=SINGLE` and `mode=MULTIPLE`. Are you enabling multiple Spring profiles at startup? Have you configured it to scan specific packages? Do you have multiple `@SpringBootApplication` annotations in your project? I don't think this issue is related to your MongoDB configuration, it's related to your basic Spring configuration which you haven't included in the question.

Comment: @MarkB my answer is no for every question, I only didn't include it because it's a plain empty project downloaded from start.spring.io today, everything is on default settings.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same symptoms. It appeared that I had a Configuration class that implemented `AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration`, which caused a `MongoClient` to be created twice. Leaving the client creation to the framework and configuring it through properties solved the issue in my case.

This was tested with `Spring Boot 2.1.6-RELEASE`, with the same dependency set as the poster.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. However I don't have any Mongo related configs, the only "extraordinary" thing I'm using is an injected MongoTemplate besides the repositories.